# An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Requested resource not found

Tags: aws, dynamodb

El error me sale cuando quiero subir a AWS DynamoDB un json , y me sale el error del título , dejo la configuración usada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi json:

```
{
"BaseballStats":[
  {
    "PutRequest":{
        "Item":{
            "TeamID":{"S":"TEAMINFOKI"},
            "SK":{"S":"LLA"},
            "TeamName":{"S":"Los Angeles"}
        }
    }
  }
]
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html) de AWS, este error se debe a:

> La tabla que se ha solicitado no existe o se encuentra demasiado al principio del estado CREATING.

Una posible explicación para este error es que estés atacando a una región diferente a la utilizada por dynamoDB

Comment: Cómo puedo saber la región que debería usar? En teoría la tabla está bien creada

Comment: @RoyalUp la tabla dynamoDB la has creado en una región X. Pues esa es la región en la que tienes que estar para contactar con DynamoDB. Ahora mismo estás conectado a us-west-2... ¿en qué región has creado la base de datos?